# dynamic latex code in a matplotlib title

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex, jupyter-notebook

I am working on dynamic plots on jupyter with matplotlib, which means in a for loop each different cycle provides a different plot as in the example below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 2
plt.ion()
%matplotlib notebook

x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.grid()
plt.show()
for j in range(1,5):
    ax.set_title(r"%6.2f    $y = \frac{\sin{(\pi x j)}}{(\pi x j)}$" % j)
    y = np.sin( np.pi*x*j )/( np.pi*x*j )
    line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    time.sleep(1)
    if j != 4:
        line.remove()
```

The line "ax.set_title" provides the title which has both a constant latex code and a number that changes over the time. My issue is that I can change a number in the title out of the latex code but I really don't know how to change a piece INSIDE the latex code.

In the previous example, for each different loop, I would like not only a different plot but also a title with a different latex code which provides a different result as reported here

[image]

Is there anyone who can suggest me anything about it?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - only because you used `.format()`. The OP is using `%` formatting and the second answer to the question I linked shows a perfectly valid solution: `r"%(j)6.2f    $y = \frac{\sin{(\pi x %(j)6.2f)}}{(\pi x %(j)6.2f)}$" % {'j': j}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense to use the `format` notation.
Then you need to escape all curly brackets that need to be part of the MathText string.

```
plt.title(r"$y = \frac{{\sin{{({j}\pi)}}}}{{({j}\pi)}}$".format(j=3.14159265359))
```

[image]

To format the numbers in the `format` notation, you can define the number of decimal places (`{j:.3f}`) or use the general number format (`{j:g}`).

```
plt.title(r"$y = \frac{{\sin{{({j:.3f}\pi)}}}}{{({j:g}\pi)}}$".format(j=3.14159265359))
```

[image]

Comment: great time for f-strings too!

Comment: well wait, can you combine r- and f-strings?

Comment: @PaulH Well, you would not need `r""` because backslashes can be escaped "\\".  But since I rarely ever write code for pure python 3, so I've never used `f""`.

Comment: Almost there. The only problem is that your code provides me 10 decimal digits, how can I show only two of them?

Comment: @StefanoFedele change `{j}` to `{j:0.2f}` (0.2 = two decimal places, f = floating point)